# Read Html and pick all href from the specific comment section

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I want to read all `href` from `<a>` and `src` from a generated html,
the problem is that the *href* and *src* comes in separate comment blocks like shown below:

```
<!-- Start of the CTA Button1 -->

<a target="_blank" href="http://www.home.test.com/tes/redirector.jspx?action=ref&cname=test_EDITORIAL&ckey=63746&cc=US&lc=eng&mcr=true&cmpid=3455AM" style="cursor:hand;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none">download configuration guide&nbsp;</a>

<!-- Starting of another comment -->
```

I want to read each *href* specific to this comment so that later i know that this *href* is a part of this comment section. Anyone know how to achieve it with jquery or javascript?

I have split the whole html by `/n`. I'm getting the comment line but don't know how to fetch the `href` because it doesn't have any ids.

Comment: You can always fetch the anchor tags like this $("#comment a").each(function() {
    //Your Code   
}) without id

Comment: @Dilip my comment is this "<!-- Start of the Mast Head CTA Button -->. Are you sure this will acheive.

Comment: Just seeing your code..  FIrst I did not see the code..

Comment: So you need the href from the code right?  What is the parent of "Start of the CTA Button1"

Comment: parent can be <tbody>, <tr>, <table> any thing.

Comment: SO instead of '#comment' you put the parent tag and this code should work. try it..

Answer (score 1):

Put your links in a DIV for a better perormance.

```
var linkArray = [];
var elementsInDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv').childNodes; //get all child nodes from BODY

for (var i = 0; i < elementsInDiv.length; i++) { //Loop all childNodes
    //If child node == comment AND there is a next element...
    if (elementsInDiv[i].nodeType === 8 && elementsInDiv[i].nextElementSibling) {
        var patt = new RegExp("Start of the CTA Button1"); //...define search pattern
        //if searc pattern in comment AND the next element is an anchor...
        if (patt.test(elementsInDiv[i].textContent) && elementsInDiv[i].nextElementSibling.tagName === 'A') { 
            linkArray.push(elementsInDiv[i].nextElementSibling.href); //..append href attribute to array
        }
    }
}

console.log(linkArray); //All href attributes
```

[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/S95Hq/)

Comment: Yes, a little bit, of course. Searching in the whole DOM for elements always has impact of the performance. :-)

Comment: he he yes..:)  any way nice work around.. Plain JS without jQuery is great.. +1

Comment: @alexp ..The html format is not proper as it generated from a tool and can't have node type 8 and next siblings showing empty.

Comment: Why it can't have a node type 8? Comments are always a node type 8. I've edited my code in order to prevent errors on empty `nextElementsSiblings`

Comment: @alexP actually its a var collection from which i have to retrieve things...any suggestions....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("*")
.contents()
.filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8;})
.each(function(i,e){ 
    if(e.nodeValue.contains('Button1'))
        alert(this.nextElementSibling.href);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zM5se/202/)